# telerik asp.net mvc kendo hierarchy grid with signalR datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, signalr

Hi I create hierarchy kendo grid like in this example 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy
But this example use ajax for load data. How can I use signalr for loading data? For main table I haven't problem, data loaded, but I can't understand how to load data to child grid use signalr.

Comment: You can call the Hub and notify it that you want to load data.. But I don't see how it differs from hitting an API..

Comment: Differs with this: example use ajax and `.Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }) for reading data. But how can I pass param "#=EmployeeID#" for signalR method? I don't know how to pass param to .Read("read") when I use SignalR